# iTextSharp adds only one image from the List<Image>

Tags: c#, .net, list, pdf, itext

I want to add all images from the `List<Image>` but it adds only last image. I tried using `var` instead of `System.Drawing.Image` but it didn't help. Also, I tried changing the ordering of lines to make sure that it is not some logical mistake but it didn't help either.

```
SaveFileDialog svg = new SaveFileDialog();
svg.ShowDialog();
Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35);
PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(svg.FileName + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));

doc.Open();
foreach (System.Drawing.Image image in images)
{ 
    iTextSharp.text.Image im = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff);

    if (im.Height > im.Width)
    {            
        float percentage = 0.0f;
        percentage = 700 / im.Height;
        im.ScalePercent(percentage * 100);
    }
    else
    {
        float percentage = 0.0f;
        percentage = 540 / im.Width;
        im.ScalePercent(percentage * 100);
    }

    im.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.BOX;
    im.BorderColor = iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK;
    im.BorderWidth = 3f;
    doc.Add(im);
    doc.NewPage();
}
doc.Close();
```

What is the problem? `foreach` works fine displaying those images in `pictureboxes`. I don't understand why it doesn't work with `iTextSharp`.

Comment: Where is `images` defined? That's probably where the problem lies.

Comment: Images are defined like `public List<System.Drawing.Image> images { get; set; }` and I populate that `List` through scanning process with: `images = this.ScannerDevice.PerformScan().ToList();`. After that I display those images in `flowLayoutPanel` in little `pictureBoxes` so I am sure that those images exist in the `List`

Answer (score 0):

Your code *does work* as expected.

Either you're not looking at the right output `pdf` file in the right folder or you don't have different images in your loop (the former being more likely, based on what you wrote...)

Anyway, I can *confirm* that the code in your post produces pages with different images.

**Edit**

First try by setting the output file path *without the file dialog* and then follow a simple tutorial to see how to manage the event handler of the dialog, for example [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/savefiledialog)

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // When user clicks button, show the dialog.
        saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void saveFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get file name.
        string name = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
        // Write to the file name selected.
        // ... You can write the text from a TextBox instead of a string literal.
        // insert the code for the pdf here
    }
```

Also try saving the images to disk before (so that you can double check them later) and then load them from their files

```
            System.Drawing.Image[] images = new System.Drawing.Image[3];
            images[0] = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"\\My Pictures\pic1.bmp");
            images[1] = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"\\My Pictures\pic2.JPG");
            //etc...
```

Comment: I acquire images from scanner `images = this.ScannerDevice.PerformScan().ToList();`. Later on, I display those images from the `List` in `flowLayoutPanel` through `foreach loop` so I am pretty sure that images are there.

Comment: delete your output pdf, directly write the path as a string without the SaveFileDialog and check the it is created again by your pgm

Comment: Sadly, it didn't work. Path was alright. When I open the pdf, the last image acquired is added. Previous images aren't there. I am starting to think that it adds images one over another on the same page but the code looks fine to me

Comment: @fox can you save the images to disk and load them from their files? Look at the last lines in my edit as a starting draft

Comment: I don't quite understand the question but It has to be easy to use without unnecessary memory waste. I imagine after succeeding this to choose from `flowLayoutPanel` which images will be added to PDF. It will be a part of `Document Management System` that I'm building so it has to be easy and simple

Comment: @fox it's only for debugging purposes: you want to be sure that if you save those image to files and load them back, then they are printed into the pdf. So you can double check the images saved on disk and the pdf and exclude that the issue is in this part of code eventually

Comment: When I started to do this app I had issues with `WIA` so I checked all possible problems that might be causing loss of images but I solved it and I'm absolutely sure that those images are there. Maybe `foreach` doesn't work properly with iTextSharp and `for loop` isn't of any help here.